# how to input file path when writing to a file?

Tags: python

I am using windows 10 so I use '\' for current folder.  below 'input' is a folder name under current folder. The file will be written under input subfolder of current folder.

can anyone help me find why the below is not working?  Thank you!

```
---> 37         a_file = open('..\\input\\'+'df_timedata_dict_'+area.lower()+'.pkl', "wb")
     38         pickle.dump(df_timedata_dict, a_file)
     39         a_file.close()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\input\\df_timedata_dict_prea1.pkl'
```

Comment: Is the `'input' folder in the same folder that your program is located in?

Comment: yes Nathan, 'input' folder is same folder

Comment: Alright, then you should remove the `'..\\'` from the start of your file string. The `'..'` part will make the program look for the 'input' folder in the folder above where your program is.

Comment: I seee, Thanks Nathan, I should use .\\input instead of ..\\input. It is solved now! I appreciate it

Comment: While that will work, if the 'input' folder is in the same folder as your program you do not even need the `'.\'`. If you just put `'input\\filename.file'`, python look for the 'input' folder inside the same folder as the program.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I removed it